# Why don't these two string equal each other?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to compare two strings in python and for some reason they just aren't matching.

I've made sure there's no whitespace and they're both string types, but still no luck, even when they're exactly the same.

```
if versions['ksp_version'] is self.version:
```

The strings are both '1.0.2' and I've tried both `is` and `==` with no luck.

Is there a better way to compare strings in python that I'm just missing?

EDIT: Some more context.

So, I added these lines and printed out the variables.

```
print versions['ksp_version']
print type(versions['ksp_version'])
print "===="
print self.version
print type(self.version)
```

And here's what we got.

```
1.0.2
<type 'str'>
====
1.0.2
<type 'str'>
```

Based on that, they look the same. They both have been stripped of whitespace using `.strip()`.

Comment: Where are "these two strings" advertised by the title? I just see a huge program.

Comment: `is` is just flat-out wrong here. You don't care if the two strings are the same object. How are you verifying that `versions['ksp_verison']` and `self.version` are identical?

Comment: What Stefan said. If you're referring to the line `if versions['ksp_version'] is self.version`, then `is` certainly isn't correct. That checks object identity, not value equality. (Like, is this the exact same thing stored in exactly the same place in the computer's memory.)

Comment: Please try to reduce the code to only the parts that are relevant. As is, we don't see these strings so it's hard to help. Both == and is should cover the truth test so there must be something else wrong here, maybe other hidden characters

Comment: Thinking out loud -- are you _sure_ they are both strings? `'2' == u'2' == r'2'`, but `'2' != 2`.

Comment: Just removed all the code that doesn't matter and updated with the actual strings.

Comment: Two-Bit Alchemist, `versions['ksp_version']` starts as unicode, but I'm wrapping it in `str()` when using it, so it's changed into a string.

Comment: You might want to use `print map(ord, self.version)` and `print map(ord, version['ksp_version'])` to make sure you know *exactly* what bytes are in each string.

Comment: And add `print versions['ksp_version'] == self.version`. Let's make sure you're actually right about the comparison result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing the actual strings. When you read from a file, be sure to `strip` the line you're comparing to get rid of potential `\n`s at the end:

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
  for line in f:
    print line == "asd"
    print line.strip() == "asd"
```

prints

```
False
True
```

for `input.txt`:

```
asd
```

`is` will only yield `True` for strings that are the same object, i.e. strings *known for certain* are initialized to the same value before runtime.